# jQuery 'and' 'or' conditional syntax in selector?

Tags: jquery

I know that in php that `||` is an 'or' operator but how can I use it in jQquery?

```
if ($("#shift1" || "#shift2" || "#shift3").is(":checked")){
    $('#mon').css({
        'background-color': '#88CC44',
        'color':'white'
    });
} else {
    $('#mon').css({
        'background-color': 'grey',
        'color':'white'
    });
}
```

I want this to work if any of `#shift1` or `#shift2` or `#shift3` is checked but so far it only works for the id selected first on the list. How is this done in jQuery, and also what about an 'and' instead of an 'or' is it `&&`?

Comment: In JavaScript (jQuery is a JS library) `"#shift1" || "#shift2" || "#shift3"` evaluates to `"#shift1"`  so your first line is equivalent to `if($("#shift1").is(":checked")){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` is the 'or' operator in JavaScript too - however in a selector it doesn't work with that syntax. jQuery selectors use CSS syntax, so to select multiple elements (aka an 'or' operation) you separate them by comma:

```
$("#shift1, #shift2, #shift3")
```

Also note that you can simplify and DRY your code with the use of a ternary:

```
$('#mon').css({
    'background-color': $("#shift1, #shift2, #shift3").is(":checked") ? '#88CC44' : 'grey',
    'color':'white'
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Can also make something like this, which allow you to add other checkbox without changing your javascript.

```
$('#mon').css({
    'background-color': $('[id^="shift"]:checked').length > 0 ? '#88CC44' : 'grey',
    'color':'white'
});
```

`$('[id^="shift"]:checked')` looks for checked element width an id that begins with the string `shift`

Comment: You're missing the quotes around the selector. I'd also suggest the use of `id^=shift` as using the contains selector means that you'd match on `not-shift1` as well as `shift1`.